# tkinter get selection radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I append the priority  of this application to the file as seen in the code below?

```
    #Option boxes for assigning a priority level to the request
    priority = StringVar()
    Radiobutton(self.f4, text = "High", variable=priority, value="1").grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)
    Radiobutton(self.f4, text = "Low", variable=priority, value="2").grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)


    #Button for "Confirm application"
    self.app_con = Button(self.f4, text=" Confirm and finish ", command=self.apphistory)
    self.app_con.grid(row=4, column=2


def apphistory(self):
    fo = open("Application_History.txt", "a")
    fo.writelines(["Priotiry: "+str(priority.get()),"\n"])
    fo.close
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code you provided?

Comment: NameError: name 'priority' is not defined

Comment: ok, so ask yourself "why is priority not defined?". Think about the difference between local variables, global variables, and instance variables.

Comment: `priority` appears to be a local variable of the function above `apphistory()`. Change it to `self.priority = StringVar()` and make all further references as `self.priority`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

> variable=priority

to

> variable=self.priority

This way, the Radiobutton knows where to search for the variable (in your program / class) instead of looking for it in the Radiobutton-Class itself.

And as mentioned in the comments, you need to create the variable

> self.priority

Comment: You can't just change that one line. You also have to _create_ `self.priority`.

Answer (score 0):

Your scope is obviously wrong.
Try something like this:

```py
 self.app_con = Button(self.f4, text=" Confirm and finish ", command=lambda:self.apphistory(priority))
...
def apphistory(self, priority):
    fo = open("Application_History.txt", "a")
    fo.writelines(["Priotiry: "+str(priority.get()),"\n"])
    fo.close()
```